# What does the tilde (~) represent in .NET? i.e currentStyle &= ~(int) (WindowStyles.WS_BORDER);

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a VB developer currently deciphering an application written in C#. Generally I can find the answer through Google. But I'm lost on this. What is the tilde (~) used for in C#??

Here is a snip-it containing the expression:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Updates the window style for the parent form.
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateStyle()
        {
            // remove the border style
            Int32 currentStyle = Win32Api.GetWindowLong(Handle, GWLIndex.GWL_STYLE);
            if ((currentStyle & (int)(WindowStyles.WS_BORDER)) != 0)
            {
                currentStyle &= ~(int) (WindowStyles.WS_BORDER);
                Win32Api.SetWindowLong(_parentForm.Handle, GWLIndex.GWL_STYLE, currentStyle);
                Win32Api.SetWindowPos(_parentForm.Handle, (IntPtr) 0, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                                      (int) (SWPFlags.SWP_NOZORDER | SWPFlags.SWP_NOSIZE | SWPFlags.SWP_NOMOVE |
                                             SWPFlags.SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWPFlags.SWP_NOREDRAW | SWPFlags.SWP_NOACTIVATE));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the [bitwise NOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/46zxf1c0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In this case the following code:

```
currentStyle &= ~(int) (WindowStyles.WS_BORDER);
```

can be interpreted as: Casting the `WindowStyles.WS_BORDER` enum to an `int`, take the inverse bits (using the `~` operator) and merge them with the value held in `currentStyle` using `&` (bitwise AND).  Finally, store the result back to the `currentStyle` variable.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the the response!!